# save batch dir output to a variable

Tags: batch-file

I have a partial file name.  I am doing a dir with wildcard to get the complete file name. I am looking for a way to check if file exist then save the complete filename to a variable.

so far this is not working.

```
    if exist file_00001_%Yr%%Mth%0%newDate%*.pcap (
        echo file is here
        FOR /F %i IN ('dir file_00001_%Yr%%Mth%0%newDate%*.pcap') DO SET newTestFile=%i
        echo %newTestFile%
    ) else (
        echo file is not here
    )
```

My code does verify that the file does exist but once i get the filename I want to save it into a variable to be able to strip off the randomly created part of the filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for sure you need delayed expansion and you need to use dir /b to strip unnecessary data and double `%` for the tokens:

```
 setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
 if exist file_00001_%Yr%%Mth%0%newDate%*.pcap (
    echo file is here
    FOR /F %%i IN ('dir /b /a-d file_00001_%Yr%%Mth%0%newDate%*.pcap') DO SET "newTestFile=%%~i"
    echo !newTestFile!
) else (
    echo file is not here
)
```

or you can optimize the code

```
 setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
 if exist file_00001_%Yr%%Mth%0%newDate%*.pcap (
    echo file is here
    FOR  %%i IN ("file_00001_%Yr%%Mth%0%newDate%*.pcap") DO SET "newTestFile=%%i"
    echo !newTestFile!
) else (
    echo file is not here
)
```

Comment: I am getting this from the optomized code above.  

file is here
        dir file_00001_20150609*.pcap
        file_00001_20150609*.pcap
        file is here
        dir file_00001_20150609*.pcap

I want to get the complete filename not just the partial name which is what I have right now. The complete filename is.
file_00001_201506094578902.pcap the 4578902 part of the file is a random generated string.  I am looking for a way to get that string.  So once I have the complete filename as a variable i can do that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why people use `for /F ... in ('dir /b ...` to search for files when the plain `for` command was designed (more than 25 years ago) for this purpose:

```
set "newTestFile="
for %%i in (file_00001_%Yr%%Mth%0%newDate%*.pcap) do set newTestFile=%%i
if defined newTestFile (
   echo file is here: %newTestFile%
) else (
   echo file is not here
)
```

BTW the error in your code is that `%i` FOR parameters must have double percent signs: `%%i` and `dir` command must include `/b` switch.